# Subtract dataframe rows by a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I have an analysis result table

```
         Name  Analysis  Result                 Date    Type
0      Doe J.  Albumine    10.6   23.02.2021 8:07:22  before
1      Doe J.  Albumine     6.5   25.03.2021 8:08:09   after
2     Pine C.  Albumine    13.3   25.03.2021 9:17:54  before
3     Pine C.  Albumine    11.0   22.02.2021 9:25:54   after
4  Jackson D.  Albumine    14.2  23.02.2021 10:51:38  before
5   Jackson D  Albumine    12.2           23.03.2021   after
6  Schafer L.  Albumine     8.4  25.02.2021 10:39:39  before
7  Schafer L.  Albumine     9.3  25.03.2021 12:06:15   after
```

My goal is to calculate the difference between two analyses of each patient (these are all fictional) based on 'Type' column and obtain a following table:

```
     Name  Before  After  Difference
0  Doe j.    10.6    6.5         3.9
```

I've tried groupby but didn't succeed. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with subtract:

```
df = df.pivot('Name','Type','Result').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
df['diff'] = df['before'].sub(df['after'])

print (df)
         Name  after  before  diff
0      Doe J.    6.5    10.6   4.1
1  Jackson D.   12.2    14.2   2.0
2     Pine C.   11.0    13.3   2.3
3  Schafer L.    9.3     8.4  -0.9
```

---

If error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates, it means for same `Name, Type` are 2 or more values like:

```
print (df)
         Name  Analysis  Result                 Date    Type
0      Doe J.  Albumine    10.6   23.02.2021 8:07:22  before <- duplicate Doe J., before
0      Doe J.  Albumine    10.6   23.02.2021 8:07:22  before <- duplicate Doe J., before
1      Doe J.  Albumine     6.5   25.03.2021 8:08:09   after
2     Pine C.  Albumine    13.3   25.03.2021 9:17:54  before
3     Pine C.  Albumine    11.0   22.02.2021 9:25:54   after
4  Jackson D.  Albumine    14.2  23.02.2021 10:51:38  before
5  Jackson D.  Albumine    12.2           23.03.2021   after
6  Schafer L.  Albumine     8.4  25.02.2021 10:39:39  before
7  Schafer L.  Albumine     9.3  25.03.2021 12:06:15   after
```

Possible solution with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`. If need first matched value use `aggfunc='first'`

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Type',values='Result', aggfunc='sum').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
df['diff'] = df['before'].sub(df['after'])

print (df)
         Name  after  before  diff
0      Doe J.    6.5    21.2  14.7 <- 21.2 because sum
1  Jackson D.   12.2    14.2   2.0
2     Pine C.   11.0    13.3   2.3
3  Schafer L.    9.3     8.4  -0.9
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the next error: ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape```